# BQ 2014-10-26 23:00 bug

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running this 
select timestamp('2014-10-25 23:00:00')
and get 2014-10-26 23:00:00 UTC and not 2014-10-25 23:00:00 UTC

it's only happen on this specific date and hour .
does anyone has solution for this ?

Comment: Please double check, this works fine for me.

Comment: i run this again - select timestamp('2014-10-25 23:00:00') and still get the 2014-10-26 23:00:00

Comment: Aviv is not hallucinating - I can repro this if I set my time zone to UTC+2:00

Comment: You might have some Javascript plugin/extension activated. If you can reproduce from the code/command line, please post the code examples.

Comment: please include jobids to debug further

Comment: See my response to your other question. This looks like the UI has a timezone rendering issue.

Comment: job_id = glowing-indexer-494:job_HHU7MIznZUlfAey8wI4CS2RwHcc

Comment: this problem is showed up also in my server table loading, so we can't say that it's relate due to UI and timezone issue